# How to fix "Connection Reset" when using Apache HttpClient in java

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I am making REST calls to a remote server using Apache httpClient version 4.5.2.
The connection succeeds most of the times , however we randomly get below exception.

```
Reason:javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
```

In order to fix this issue , I have enabled the keep alive strategy as per the below document.
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html

Questions:

1. How to verify if keep alive strategy is actually in place and working properly.
   can we print any headers or logs ?
2. How to confirm if remote server is also supporting keep alive strategy

Comment: "at an interval of 5 to 6 hours" -- can you please explain what exactly this means?

Comment: I meant I don't get this error continuously. it occurs randomly

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Hi @SSG - I am experiencing the same issue as yours with 4.5.13 - can you please share if you have found a better fix to this or if you are still using the keep-alive strategy? Much thanks!

Comment: Hi @Calvin 
I am still using keep-alive strategy only, below is the doc for reference.
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html

Comment: Thanks! The custom keep-alive did not work for me. The disconnects turn out coming from the infrastructure that is hosting the remote service my app talks to. To work around this I would have my app retry the same request as soon as the first one failed.

Answer (score 0):

To verify whether keep-alive strategy works and whether the remote server supports it, we can extend the [`DefaultClientConnectionReuseStrategy`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultClientConnectionReuseStrategy.html) to log the status line and headers from `HttpResponse` and whether the superclass returns `true`. If strategy returns `true`, the response object is passed next to the default or custom `ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy` to determine duration.

If the remote service returns the protocol version `HTTP/1.0` and supports keep-alive, we would get a ["Keep-Alive"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive) header in the response with parameters. On the other hand, if the remote service returns `HTTP/1.1`, it is expected to always support keep-alive and we might not get this header.